# why doesn't it want to check and then insert

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-insert

for school i have to make a portfolio with a working login and registration system, the login part kinda works but by the regestration part i kinda got stuck. so why doesn't want to insert the users data after it checks the database of the username and email already exists? (hope u dont mind, but i am still a student who recently started with coding)

```
<?php
    include_once 'db_connect.php';
    include_once 'psl-config.php';

    $error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid!</p>';
    }
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if (strlen($password) != 128) {
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
    }
    $query_username = "SELECT id
    FROM members
    Where username == '$username'
    LIMIT 1";
    $available_username = array();
    if ($resultUsername = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_username)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultUsername) > 0) {
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already exists!</p>';
        }
    }
    $query_email = "SELECT id
    FROM members
    Where email == '$email'
    LIMIT 1";
    $available_email = array();
    if ($resultEmail = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_email)) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultEmail) > 0) {
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email adress already exists!</p>';
        }
    }
    if (empty($error_msg)) {
        $ipadress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE));
        $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);
        if (!$tableRowEmail = 1) {
            $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO members (username, email, ipadress, password, salt) VALUES ($username, $email, $ipadress, $password, $random_salt)";
            if (!mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqlinsert)) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./register_success.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't it want to register me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961792/why-doesnt-it-want-to-register-me)

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess: You use `==` in your sql statements. I'm quite sure you should only use `=`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks guys but it still doesn't want to insert the data into a database

Comment: You need to use a combination of both answers to (possibly) fix this. And if that still doesn't work, then check your column names and types. @JustinVeenis

Comment: the problem could be your if statement
if (!$tableRowEmail = 1)

- the variable is not set anywhere
- you should use == to compare variables to values

Comment: Plus, this variable isn't doing anything `$available_username` @JustinVeenis

Answer (score 0):

Field values are missing single quote ' 
all the fields are varchar datatype.Single quotes should be used for string values.

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO members (username, email, ipadress, password, salt) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$ipadress', '$password', '$random_salt')";
```

Comment: it still doesnt want to insert the data into the database